# Создание кнопки на панели в Хром

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как создать кнопку на панели в хроме? Она должна по клику открывать ссылку в новой вкладке.

[image: вот сюда нужно кнопку]

> Открыть в новой вкладке

Comment: Создание расширений для хрома процесс не очень сложный. Требуется немного знать JavaScript и HTML. Но если Вы планируете выставить свое расширение на всеобщее обозрение и сделать доступным через Chrome Web Store - придется заплатить за лицензию (стоит она всего 5$). А если расширение чисто для себя, то о том как это делается, можно почитать тут: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2714278?hl=ru

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы все было ясно, приведу небольшой работающий пример, который помогает реализовать задачу указанную в вопросе.

Создание расширения процесс достаточно простой и понятный. Разумеется для создания сложных расширений требуется более серьезное знание JavaScript.

И так, наше расширение должно уметь открывать в новой вкладке страницу по нажатии на иконку.

Для начала создаем манифест файл, который содержит в себе все необходимые данные о расширении. Файл должен называться manifest.json. Вот его содерживое.

```
{
    "name": "HTML5",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "icons": {
        "128": "128.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Нажмите на иконку HTML5",
        "default_icon" : "128.png"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs"],
    "background":{
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

**name** - название нашего расширения для Google Chrome. Под этим именен он будет показываться в списке расширений.

**version** - версия расширения. Указывается на усмотрение разработчика, но в соотвествии с определенными общепринятыми правилами. Об этом можно отдельно почитать [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

**manifest_version** - версия нашего манифеста. Это значение фиксированное и его менять не надо.

**icons** - главная иконка нашего расширения размером 128 на 128. Формат файла -  png

**browser_action** - координирует взаимодействие работы с браузером.

**default_title** - текст, всплывающий при наведении курсора на иконку.

**default_icon** - иконка для панели расширений (собственно на нее мы будем нажимать чтобы перейти по ссылке)

**permissions** - указываем действия, на которые наше расширение должно получить доступ. В нашему случае это возможность работать с ТАБ-ами.

**background** - указываем данные для фоновой страницы. Какие страницы, скрипты итд загружать в фоновом режиме. Мы лишь указываем на файл background.js.

При нажатии на иконку расширения, в фоновом режиме запустится и исполнится код, который лежит в background.js

Содержание файла background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){

  chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://www.w3.org/html/logo/" });
});
```

Создаем папку и копируем в нее все три файла: manifest.json, background.js, 128.png

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее переходим в Google Chrome во вкладку Расширения (Extensions) и нажимаем на кнопку "Загрузить распакованное расширение" (Load unpacked extension). Указываем на нашу папку (которая содержит три файла) и расширение будет установлено.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иконка появится там где ее ждут :-). Кликаем и переходим на нужный адрес.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]